# Page Jumping to Middle of Page

Tags: php, javascript, html, anchor

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a page jump on our [testimonials page here](http://mountainfoodstorage.com/index.php/testimonials). If it doesn't happen at first, click onto a link in the primary nav and then click onto the testimonials link again. It goes right above the contact page.

I've been looking for a page anchor, but can't find one.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the issue in Magento... The fix is to change the following code in contacts/form.phtml (or wherever your form is being called from).

Before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

After:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', false);
//]]>
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's may be because the focus is given to the first input in your page, which is at the end of the page.

Note: you have a javascript error about `$("#year")`

Comment: Hey there!

Thank you for pointing out the JS error. I'm trying to fix that up now but why would the focus go to the first input? Is there a way to not have that happen?

Comment: Not sure but the input is not focused by default, so, maybe some javascript code is doing that..? Look at thsi example : http://jsfiddle.net/gfBaE/ (if you remove the jquery focus command, the input will not be focused by default).

Comment: You helped me out significantly!

I'm answering my ticket right now. :) Credit given to you for the answer.

Comment: mark as best answer if its the case ;) and tell us if you have found if there is a JS line of code putting the focus

Comment: Indeed ! if you are looking to your file `http://mountainfoodstorage.com/js/varien/form.js`, you will see in the initialize method that you give as second param a boolean to say if you want to give the ofcus on the first input of your form. So the library will add this focus with js :)